# How to download spring release 5.1.5 or above version jars

Tags: spring, spring-boot, eclipse, spring-mvc, dependencies

I'm trying to develop spring MVC project for which I need spring release 5.1.5 jar files. I'm unable to download required jar files from jfrog . Is there any other source?

When I click on the links it redirected to Jfrog website login page and no jar files were there.

Comment: A web search for [`spring mvc dependency`](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=spring+mvc+dependency) gets me to Maven Central. At the [5.1.5 release](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/5.1.5.RELEASE) known vulnerabilities are listed.

Comment: @howlger The thing is I've created a dynamic web project in eclipse rather than a maven type. So I'm finding it difficult to add the jars manually.

Comment: @YashwanthGundagani see if this helps https://www.edureka.co/community/4028/how-to-import-a-jar-file-in-eclipse#:~:text=You%20can%20add%20a%20jar,Simple%20as%20that.

Comment: [This does not contradict each other.](https://www.learnbestcoding.com/post/1/how-to-setup-a-dynamic-web-project-with-maven-and-eclipse) Also, you can use Maven Central with other build systems than Maven, including downloading a JAR manually.